# More points for votes from top users

Tags: discussion, votes

Have Stack Exchange considered making a vote from a highly ranked user, say 20k+, result in a greater number of reputation points being awarded than a vote from a lower ranked user ?

If so, and such a proposal was rejected, what was the rationale ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the answer to whether or not there has been a proposal, but I know that it would be rejected hands down. Just because a user has a high reputation doesn't mean that by default they are an expert in what they are voting on and therefore the recipient of their vote deserves more or less points than any other user who votes on that same question or answer.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been proposed on Meta.stackoverflow.com before and rejected for similar reasoning